# ¿Porque no captura la excepción?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, excepciones

Tengo este trozo de código para realizar el signup de un nuevo usuario en NodeJS con passport como middleware de autenticación. El caso es que provoco error para que lance una excepción y así ver donde y cómo tengo que manejarlo, pero no está siendo capturada. aquí pongo un ejemplo:

```
passport.use('signup', new localStrategy(
    {
        passReqToCallback: true,
        usernameField: 'email'
    },
    async function (req, email, password, done) {
        try{
            let findOrCreateUser = async function () {
                let result = await userModel.findOneUser(email);
                if (result != null) {
                    console.log("El usuario ya existe");
                    done(null, false);
                } else {
                    let user = new userModel();
                    user.username = req.body.username;
                    user.email = email;
                    user.password = await createHash(password);
                    await userModel.newUser(user); 
                    return done(null, user);    
                }
            }
            await process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
        }catch(e){
            console.log("asdasd");
            done(null, false);
        }
    }
))
```

y la función createHash en la que provoco un error intencionadamente llamando a la función genSal, en lugar de genSalt.

```
async function createHash(password){
    try{
        let salt = await bcrypt.genSal(20);
        let hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        return hash;
    }catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Porque no la captura: Unhandled exception.

¿Debría de colocar los try/catch en otro lugar?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una interesante pregunta, vamos a intentar reproducir el escenario, construyendo un código similar poco a poco.

```js
async function lanzaError() {
  throw 'Error!';
}

try {
  lanzaError();
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Capturado', error);
}
```

Vemos que el error no se captura y por eso no sale en la consola del fragmento.

Pero sí aparece en la consola del navegador, podemos verlo pulsando <kbd>F12</kbd> o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Mays</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Probemos de otro modo, capturando el error de la promesa.

Para esto necesitaremos usar `await` (y por tanto crear una función que llamaré `main`, ya que JS no admite el uso de `await` fuera de una función asíncrona):

```js
async function lanzaError() {
  try {
    await noExiste();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('relanzo', e.message);
    throw e.message;
  }
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await lanzaError();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Capturado', error);
  }
}

main();
```

Si obligamos a esperar a que se ejecute y resuelva la promesa, entonces funciona.

Pero en tu escenario hay algo más: estás definiendo una función asíncrona que se le pasa a [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args). Pero `nextTick(fn)` **no** es una función asíncrona, su comportamiento es similar a `setTimeout(fn)`. Por tanto, el `await` que has puesto delante es totalmente ignorado:

```js
async function lanzaError() {
  try {
    await noExiste();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('relanzo', e.message);
    throw e.message;
  }
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await setTimeout(lanzaError);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Capturado', error);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Ok!!!, entonces no debería de usar nextTick(), e invocar la función sola con el await. ¿Es así? Ahora capturo la excepción. ¡Muchas gracias! Por otra parte, ¿Cómo debería de usar nextTick()?.

Comment: nextTick se suele usar para algo que quieras realizar tras una tarea que ya has completado. Por ejemplo, para liberar recursos